# Send character by character via websocket or Data channel with WebRTC?

Tags: javascript, html, websocket, webrtc

is it possible to send character by character via websocket or datachannel with webrtc(in future)? I am looking for the real time text communication between two or more browser and editing the text by more than one user in parallel . For example: One writes a text (character by character) and another corrects the same text at same time.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I haven't used WebRTC data channels, but given that their API is similar to that of WebSockets I think what you need is absolutely doable, you just want to send one character at a time, or send a message containing character and its position and any other info that you need.
Something in the lines of

```
var websocket = new WebSocket("server address");

websocket.onmessage = function(message) {
   console.log("Character sent: ", JSON.parse(message));
};

// somewhere in your code
websocket.send(JSON.stringify({
   position: 42,
   character: 'a'
}));
```

Comment: It sounds easy. How will the character be set at position into textbox? Will the function websocket.send be executed after keyup?

Comment: You need to listen to either `keyUp` or `input` events. `input` is better because it fired only on real input whereas `keyUp` is fired on every key press (enter, arrows). If in your application users only enter text or only can delete the last character then you don't need a position at all, all you need is to have two messages types one for input and one for delete. If your users can edit text in arbitrary position then it becomes more difficult, but you can search Stackoverflow on how to get a cursor position and character position